# Tools to reduce generated HTML size

Tags: html, scripting, google-docs, mshtml

I'm using google docs, and some templates we are using were created using MS-Office.
The resulting HTML is fat and ugly, and the 500KB per doc limitation on google makes some cleanup mandatory.
I was able to find redundant "style" attributes and move them to some CSS class, and rename the most redundant classes names to shorter ones, which makes me save about 50% of the original size.
Are you aware of some existing tools/scripts/lib which could do this painful job for me, or at least help me to write this magic tool ?

Thanks in advance !

EDIT: I gave a try to both tidy, demoronizer and "manual rewrite":
- Input : 140Kb
- Tidy'ed : 110Kb
- Demoronized : 135Kb

So my favorite answer will be "rewrite it!"

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MS-Office makes crappy HTML, period. You're better of spending time rebuilding the HTML from the original text than trying to walk through that minefield.

I made a few macros that do some search/replace functions on Word to do basic things like wrap `<p>` tags around paragraphs and stuff like that, then re-markup the whole thing from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [tidy](http://tidy.sf.net) it will clean up many things.

Answer (score 0):

Without commenting on its name, I could mention [demoronizer](http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/demoroniser/), which the author describes as:

> ...a Perl program available for downloading from this site which corrects numerous errors and incompatibilities in HTML generated by, or edited with, Microsoft applications.

YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

One of my favourite utilties now is actually Windows Live Writer - it does a neat job of stripping rubbish out of Word doc files. Some might disagree but I use it quite often!